# Retention of backups

Tags: linux, bash

im doing daily backups via bash script using rsync.

the incremental backups are going into a dated folder based on this line of script

```
rsync -avz --link-dest=$LinkDest root@123.123.55.90:/data/backup/"$j" /home/backup/website/$f_date --bwlimit=10000 --log-file=/logs/rsync_"$j"_"$r_date".log
```

so i will end up with folders as follows

2014-05-01
2014-05-02
2014-05-03

what i want to do is make a script that will delete these folders once they are 30 days old.

so i dont end up with a
2014-05-01
2014-06-01

thus giving me 30 days retention.

[Update]
heres another method idea,

if i change the backup script to place the backups into a folder called "month(date +%B)"/"day(date +%F)"

```
rsync -avz --link-dest=$LinkDest root@123.123.55.90:/data/backup/"$j" /home/backup/website/$m_date/$f_date --bwlimit=10000 --log-file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/rsync_"$j"_"$r_date".log
```

i could have another script that checks what the month is and deletes the other folder names? but now im stuck as to how to look at folder contents and delete all folders but not the one matching m_date=$(date +%B)

```
#!/bin/bash

LinkDest=/home/backup/website/
m_date=$(date +%B)

find $LinkDest . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "$m_date" -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres my solution to this

incremental backup script

```
#!/bin/bash


r_date=$(date "+%d-%m-%y")
f_date=$(date +%F)
servers=("123.111.178.38" "192.237.38.167" "118.137.95.142)

for j in "${servers[@]}"
do

echo "server:/data/backup/$j /home/backup/website/$j"

rsync -avz root@123.123.123.200:/data/backup/"$j" /home/backup/website/full --bwlimit=10000     --log-file=/usr/local/src/backup/logs/rsync_"$j"_"$r_date".log

done
```

which creates a folder within website called "month" so April May June etc and inside each month a daily dated backup.

then on the 28th of each month. crontab runs the retention script which is as follows

```
#!/bin/bash

LinkDest=/home/backup/website/
m_date=$(date +%B)

echo "Deleteing Old Backups Started"

find $LinkDest/ -xdev -depth -mindepth 1 -not -path "*$m_date*" -not -path "*full*" -exec  rm -Rf {} \;

echo "Deleting Old Backups Completed"
```

Comment: What happens if your backup fails... your clean up script continues... you have no more backup.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `find` with the `-mtime` flag to find these files. E.g.:

```
find . -mtime 30 -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: Yikes. Consider using the `-exec` flag to `find` or even `find … -print0 | xargs -0`. As written this could result in fairly dangerous output.

Comment: Or use the `-delete` action (should be available on Linux). Files named `-rf` and `*` are problematic otherwise.

Comment: @kojiro arg, indeed. `-exec` is way more elegant.

Comment: Ack, no! This won't just delete backups older than 30 days, it'll delete files within those backups that haven't been modified in 30 days.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, yes thats what i thought. it would be ok if the backups were say zipped but this proves to be a lengthy processes.